# A method with tryparse using min and max limits

Tags: c#, methods, max, min, tryparse

I'm trying to make a method such as this

```
    public static bool GetInteger(string stringToConvert, out int intOutValue, int minLimit, int maxLimit)
```

I want it to check if the value is within the min and max range that I specify with the in-values. The parsing is just

```
            int.TryParse(stringToConvert, out intOutValue)
```

but how do I now check if the value of "intOutValue" is within range? It keeps telling me that it is a bool-value...
Any help on how to do this would be greatly appriciated! (I'm pretty new to programming, and especially in c#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to do comparisons based on the result of the call to `TryParse` then therein lies your problem; that returns a boolean to indicate success or not (hence the *Try*). So you need to compare the `inOutValue` as that's what has been populated.

```
public static bool GetInteger(string input, out int result, int min, int max) {
  return int.TryParse(input, out result) && (result >= min && result <= max);
}
```

There is no need for an `out` param here, and I'd even say the method naming is bad, unless you actually want the value to be accessible after the fact.

Comment: Ah, this was my problem! I was trying to compare the wrong thing. Thanks.

Comment: Also yes, I want the value to be accessible I'm going to use it in other programs (windows forms etc.) so that I can convert ints and doubles from strings.

Edit: Is there any way I can overload this method to just use a min value and no maximum value(just passing the maxvalue)? Or do I need a whole new method for that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to check if it is also in the given range, as well as a valid int. In which case you could do:

```
public static bool GetInteger(string stringToConvert, out int intOutValue, int minLimit, int maxLimit)
{
    bool parsed = int.TryParse(stringToConvert, out intOutValue);
    return parsed && intOutValue >= minLimit && intOutValue <= maxLimit;
}
```